# Constructing objects from data in multiple arrays: copy or reference the data?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have a data source that constructs multiple arrays of data. Each array are associated to each other by their offsets (all arrays are the same length). I am using a library that works on singular objects of this data through a public interface.

An example with two pieces of data `a` and `b` that make up single objects.

```
// three 'objects'
static int a[] = { 5, 6, 7};
static double b[] = {402, 24014, 52.3};
```

And I have this interface of the object that the library uses:

```
class ISomeInterface {
   public:
    virtual ~ISomeInterface{}
    virtual int GetA() const = 0;
    virtual double GetB() const = 0;
}
```

How would I best to get an interface 'view' this data if the `ISomeInterface` can be added to a vector, get sorted and filtered in the library.

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<ISomeInterface> > data;
```

Would I just construct a class that points to the index in the data arrays? Assuming the references to the array are accessible:

```
class MyClass : ISomeInterface {
    public:
     MyClass(int index) : _index(index) {};

     virtual int GetA() const { return a[_index];}
     virtual double GetB() const { return b[_index];}
    private:
     int _index;
}
```

Or I could just copy the data from the arrays to an object:

```
class MyClass2 : ISomeInterface {
    public:
     MyClass2(int a, double b) : _a(a), _b(b) {};

     virtual int GetA() const { return _a;}
     virtual double GetB() const { return _b;}
    private:
     int _a;
     double _b;
}
```

I could potentially have a lot of data in these arrays, so I thought the first approach would avoid duplicating all the data.

Comment: This is essentially a premature optimization question. Both approaches are valid, the only reason to move things around in memory like this is if you think it will improve locality / avoid copying things unnecessarily in a way that is advantageous to you

Comment: If you make a copy, you don't see future change. With reference or index, you still see up to date value.